# Coupling constant for an object in a photon gas

Tags: thermodynamics, noise, brownian-motion

I want to model a photon gas as a bath of harmonic oscillators, and examine the effects of this bath on a system which is also a harmonic oscillator. The trouble I'm having is in relating the properties of the gas to the properties of the bath.

Quantum Noise, a book by Gardiner, gives us a general form for modelling this kind of thing: 
$$ H = H_{sys} + \sum_n^\infty\left(\frac{1}{2m}p_n^2+\frac{k_n}{2}(q_n-g_n x)^2 \right) $$
where $q_n,p_n$ give the position and momentum operators of the $n^{th}$ bath oscillator, $g_n$ gives the coupling between this bath oscillator and the system, and $x$ gives the position operator of the system under study.

The trouble I'm having is twofold. Firstly, do I model each bath mode as having the same frequency as a corresponding photon mode? Or do I have to take account of the occupation of the photon mode to work out an effective frequency for the bath oscillator?

Secondly, how do I calculate $g_n$, and should it be constant or proportional to the frequency? If I try to work this out from the fluctuations in radiation pressure that we would expect from the gas, I get lost in trying to relate that effect to the harmonic bath model.

This is all made slightly more complicated in that I am modelling light whose source has a chemical potential, so that the occupation of each mode is given by $e^{\frac{-\hbar \nu - \mu}{k T}}$.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: With $kq^2$ as the stored potential energy of the oscillators, it looks a bit strange to use this for photons.  Although photon quantum operators $a_k^\dagger, a_k$ are analogous to harmonic-oscillator operators $a^\dagger, a$, you typically don't express them in terms of position and momentum operators.

Comment: Yes that's true - the issue is basically that I want to express the photon gas in terms of a standard bath of harmonic oscillators, and hence in this language. Once in this language I can use a variety of results which are standard in open quantum systems.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fuzzy answer to a fuzzy question. First, express the interaction between your system and the bath in terms of standard photon quantum operators $a^\dagger_k, a_k$. Use substitutions $a_k^\dagger+a_k\rightarrow q$ and $i(a^\dagger_k-a_k)\rightarrow p$ to shoehorn it in the form of the Hamiltonian that you want to see. (I'm omitting all the prefactors $\hbar, m, \omega$ here). The wavevector $k$ will serve a purpose analogous to the index $n$ in your hamiltonian, so the summation $\sum_n$ will become an integration $\int \rho(k)\,d^3k$, where $\rho$ is the density of states given by your Boltzmann factor. You may have to modify that Boltzmann factor to account for the boson-like nature of photons, but maybe that's a negligible effect at your temperature.